# Prove that <p(x),q(x)>=∫P(x)q(x)ⅆx is an inner product?

Tags: inner-products

I need some help with this problem. Well I already know how to prove first condition (a) and second (b) it's so obvious, but my problem is the third one (c) which states: " $<p(x),p(x)>=0$ if and only if $p(x)=0$ ". Since (c) explicitly states: "If and only If", I don't exactly know how to prove it. I know how to go from $P(x)\geq0$ to an integral but I can't figure out the other way. Can someone please help me ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Gx0.jpg)

Comment: If the integral of a non-negative continuous function is $0$ then it is the zero function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: What is your space $V$ ? Are $p$ and $q$ polynomials, general functions, are they continuous ? etc...

Comment: First I should apologize for not using mathJax because I'm new to this.

Comment: And yeah p and q are polynomials and the exact question details is in the picture I linked. Vector space is as defined, R[x].

Comment: Thanks Kavi Rama Murthy, I think that finishes the proof.